# Custom logger for Spring cache events

Tags: spring, logging, hazelcast, spring-cache

I am using Spring Cache with Hazelcast and I wonder if there is a way to add a custom logger / interceptor for @Cacheable events (like hiting cache, putting new keys and stuff).

The only thing I have found are logs from org.springframework.cache on TRACE level, they are working pretty OK (*`2018-06-22 15:56:26,532|TRACE|||||||||||Cache entry for key 'SampleRequest{name='SAMPLE'}' found in cache 'xxxx'`*), however I need a way to write something custom.

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Maybe by using AOP on package `org.springframework.cache`

Comment: I believe that I can write AOP for AbstractCacheInvoker from spring, however I am not sure if it is best solution.